# How to get Controller and Action inside AuthorizationHandler?

Tags: c#, .net-core, identity, asp.net-core-3.1, httpcontext

I am just wondering is it possible to get `Controller` and `Action` in an `AuthorizationHandler`?! It is needed in order to be able to validate user's role based on the requested action.

I'm able to get reference to `HttpContext`. But the `HttpContext.Request.RouteValues` seems inaccessible.

Does anyone has any idea?
my code:

```
public class RoleHandler :
    AuthorizationHandler<RoleRequirement>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _context;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

    public RoleHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IUnitOfWork context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext authorizationcontext,
        RoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        var roleClaim = authorizationcontext.User.Claims
            .Where(c =>
                 c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role);

        var routeData = authorizationcontext.Resource ;


        if (ThisRoleIsAllowed(roleClaim, requirement.ActionName).Result)
            authorizationcontext.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Comment: Please share with us your `AuthorizationHandler`'s implementation.

Comment: I Share the code @PeterCsala

Comment: What is the concrete type of the `authorizationcontext.Resource`? Is it [AuthorizationFilterContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.authorizationfiltercontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1) ?

Comment: apparently it is object

Comment: @amihejazi. Yes, it is an object indeed. But it is used as a generic container. So, if you called `.GetType().Name`or `.GetType().FullName` will return the wrapped object's type.

Comment: It is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteEndpoint"

Comment: Is it called by WebAPI or MVC? In case of MVC it suppose to be a `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.AuthorizationContext` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext` instance, which does have `RouteData`.

Comment: Called By WebAPI I could get the route  of request but i want the target action because I use multiple route for my API therefore the route is not unique

Comment: You can reach it by calling the `GetEndpoint` [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointhttpcontextextensions.getendpoint) on the HttpContext. From that you can retrieve a `ControllerActionDescriptor` [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor) with following code: `.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>()`. That exposes two properties: `ControllerName` and `ActionName`

Comment: 'IHttpContextAccessor' does not contain a definition for 'GetEndpoint' and no accessible extension method 'GetEndpoint' accepting a first argument of type 'IHttpContextAccessor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Infrastructure]

Comment: You have a really unfortunate name for your `IHttpContextAccessor` parameter. `HttpContextAccesor` exposes a property called `HttpContext` [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontextaccessor.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1) First you need to retrieve that and then you can use the `GetEndpoint` extension method.

Comment: Did you manage to retrieve the `ControllerActionDescriptor`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me summarize here what we had discussed so far.
(My intention is to capture the valuable information from the comments).

The OP wants to implement a resource (*endpoint*) based **Authorization**. (The ASP.NET Core standard is the role based.) In order to do so, the following information is needed:

- The resolved controller and action name (resolved means based on the routing table, which controller's which action should handle the particular request)

Based on these and the role claim the Authorization logic easily can decide whether or not the requester is allowed to access the resource.

---

To able to retrieve the controller's name and action's name I suggested the following:

- Call the `GetEndPoint` [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointhttpcontextextensions.getendpoint) on the `HttpContext`
- Call the `GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>` on the `Endpoint`
- Access the `ControllerName` and `ActionName` on the `ControllerActionDescriptor` ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor))

So, to sum up:

```
public class RoleHandler: AuthorizationHandler<RoleRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync
      (AuthorizationHandlerContext authorizationcontext, RoleRequirement requirement)
    {
         var endpoint = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetEndpoint();
         var descriptor = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();
         var controllerName = descriptor.ControllerName;

         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I like to add one thing for anyone face same problem.I add RoleHandler in my Infrastructure layer which cause problem after moving it to my api layer the problem fade special thanks to @Peter Csala